# renderStart method not working as expected in amp-ad AMP element

Tags: amp-html

.
Hi guys,

I hope you are all doing good!

I am having some issues with using renderStart in the implementation of our adserver, was hoping to have someone check if there is any bug with renderStart or if we are doing something wrong in its implementation.

According to documentation (https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/tree/master/ads#support-for-multi-size-ad-requests) using `window.context.renderStart({width: 200, height: 100});` should automatically resize the ad on display, allowing support for multi size.
In case a resize is not possible, doc says it will center the ad.

However, this seems to not be working and calling renderStart seems to have no effect.

This can be view on the official test page from the project (https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/examples/ads.amp.html). DoubleClick added an example for resize on render (Doubleclick with overriden size

The issue is also present here:

http://jdelhommeau.dev.getforge.io/demo_amp_an.html

Using AN SSP, in which we implemented the `renderStart` method, the ad isn't resized, despite being loaded out of view (you need to scroll down to see the ad).

Is that a bug in the renderStart method? Or did we miss something in its implementation?

Thank you very much for your help.

Julien

Answer (score 0):

in my case `<amp-ad>` tag required attributes `width > 0, height > 0, layout="responsive"`